# ' TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list ' : Not understanding

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

I've seen other pages like this, but the answers were made to their code, and I am not understanding it, the error says:

> TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list

Here is the code:

```py
def get_mask(self):
    return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)

def draw_window(win, block):
    win.blit(BG_IMG, (0, 0))
    block.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    block = Block(200,200)
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

            draw_window(win, block)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

main()
```

So if you have an answer, please tell!

Comment: Where does the error occur? That isn’t your complete code, correct? Please see: [mcve], [ask]. What have you tried to solve this? I strongly recommend reading this article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you've create a list, when you've initialized `BG_IMG`:

```py
BG_IMG = [pygame.image.load(...)]
```

So the variable `BG_IMG` is not a single [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) instance. It is a list with 1 element.

Declare a single object rather than a list:

```py
BG_IMG = pygame.image.load(...)
```